# How to get phone number when incoming phone call on Flutter ios side?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, callkit, phone-state-listener

Android side is working perfect I am able to listen phonestate and when get incomingcall I can show system alert dialog with caller details, unfortunately on ios side I am not able to get phone number from incoming call, just I am only able to listen phonestates, but there is something to do because you know the app GetContacts able to do this. Is there any known way to do this?

GetContacts able to do this even with show on ios calling screen. It should be possible but how ?

Comment: You cannot get the incoming number on iOS. You can provide ios with a list of names for numbers so that it can display the name associated with a number when a call comes in but your app cannot get caller details. It is a privacy issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot at least mentally, I solved my problem with the call directory extension as you mentioned. It took me 3 days to solve it, I will write 'Medium' blog and share it here ASAP to help others